# Are there any plugins available in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am very new to groovy and i would like to know if there are any plugins available in groovy?like we have gems available in ruby which you just have to download install and use...Like wise is there anything similar available in groovy (some packages/downloadables or anything).Is there any readily available package or plugin

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with @tim_yates on that. Something very similar to the gems can be achieved via Grape annotations.

Grapes are not globally installed, they are only available to your runtime if you add the annotation. But they are downloaded and kept in you ivy cache, so only the first time will they be downloaded.

I'm no ruby specialist, but gems are more used as an external extension system, instead of an internal plugin mechanism, as the modular groovy intiative aims. Groovy is already extensible via the simple classpath, and that is how the Grapes do it, they add jars and libraries accessible to the classpath of your script.

It's true that they are not plugins, but the way you can leverage maven repositories and ivy allows you to write selfcontained groovy scripts that will pull any dependency needed for it to run.

An example from the Grape page on codehaus:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.6')
@Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring', version='2.5.6')
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

Now you can access a mysql database via the spring jdbc template.

picked from: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape

Comment: Fair point.  I guess I got the wrong end of the stick with this question